# How to make an image non-selectable in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a HTML & CSS website.
I want to put an image in there which people can not select (or drag).

Earlier, `user-select: none` worked on images and texts, but now it doesn't work on images on Chrome>50 and only works on texts.

```css
.text {
  user-select: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1.3px;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

div.image img{
  user-select: none;
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sed metus efficitur massa placerat auctor faucibus ut mi. Ut sed malesuada felis. Ut varius pharetra orci nec imperdiet. Ut quis nunc elit. Sed scelerisque libero a lacus tempor, eget iaculis augue commodo. Etiam ac elit justo. Nulla pharetra efficitur magna quis gravida. Fusce vulputate lacinia enim ac fermentum. Nullam ac aliquam metus, ac egestas arcu. Cras ac orci finibus purus iaculis mattis quis nec nisl. Proin vehicula eu diam vitae maximus. Quisque ornare a odio a maximus. Donec at nunc fermentum, commodo enim et, finibus libero. Pellentesque ornare ipsum eget ex egestas sagittis.</div>
      <div class="image"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1599009434802-ca1dd09895e7?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"></div>
    </body>
```

Notice in the above snippet that you cannot select the text, but you can select the image.

***How Do I Make The Image Unselectable???***

Comment: Bear in mind that you're showing that image on the web; there's ways of making it more difficult to select but you're sending the image to the client, so it will always be available to download.

Answer (score 1):

```
Found this on online try it out:
div.image img{
  user-select: none;
  -drag: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  width: 50%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest answer to this question is : `pointer-events`

Ok, here I'll show you an example:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="imageOne">
     <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518770660439-4636190af475?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" alt="just a pic of processor :D">
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.imageOne {
  pointer-events: none; //That's basically it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
img {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all css attr of selection

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```